# Error with syncing multiple folders in Perforce using p4.net api

Tags: synchronization, perforce, p4.net

I am using the p4.net api to sync multiple folders recursively. The number of folders can go into the hundreds with an average of seven files in each. I use the [SyncFiles](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/M_Perforce_P4_Client_SyncFiles.htm) Method (from the Client class) and my syntax looks like this :

```
myP4Connection.Client.SyncFiles(syncOptions, fs);
```

where in sync options, the only flag I pass is the `-m` for max items, which set to `int.MaxValue` and `fs` is the P4 file Spec containing the folder to be synced, and the version set to the head revision.

So the problem I face is : I never run into an exception when I try and sync one, or a few folders. When I try to sync a large set of assets, the P4 Client doesn't seem to flush it's resources and  at times it throws an exception that it couldn't sync the mentioned depot location. The folder mentioned in the exception never matches the one passed in the function call. I can get over this problem by giving a sleep at the end of each sync, but that doesn't seem like a solid fix. Is there a way I can limit the number of resources requested from Perforce, so I can sync a lot of folders asynchronously?

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you're running separate `SyncFiles` commands for each folder you want to sync?  Is there a reason you do that instead of just syncing the top level folder?

In any case you should file a support ticket with Perforce.  If there is a performance bug in P4.NET they'll need to diagnose it.